# Insert orders in Magento via SQL

Tags: mysql, magento

I have a situation where I am trying to import historical orders from an accounting package into a Magento install.
To figure out tables I needed to insert into I cleared out everything with the sales_prefix and then created an order via the Magento backend. I then looked at the sales_ tables that order had affected s it was the only record.
So I then mimicked that operation, creating SQL statements that inserted records into those tables, taking care to get the entity ID, customer ID, etc matching across them all.

The result is that I can see an order I insert on the orders main screen but when I click on one to go to the order detail I get no order information. 
The page presents itself as it should i.e. no code crash, just with the order details section empty.

The tables I inserted into are

- sales_flat_order
- sales_flat_order_item
- sales_flat_order_grid
- sales_flat_order_address (billing and shipping)
- sales_flat_order_payment
- sales_flat_order_status_history
- sales_flat_quote

I guess I'm still missing at least one table.

Can anyone point to which one?

Thanks

Comment: It would be a lot easier and safer using an existing order import functionality, rather than trying to inject stuff straight to your database.  Try putting your data into a CSV structure and importing it into Magento using something like this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bulk-import-export-orders-to-csv.html

Comment: @Axel - thanks, that looked like it would do the job. I tried out and got the exact same effect. The orders imported into database OK and I can see them listed on the orders screen but clicking on one to view the details shows no data. I double check everything and also export and then import some orders from the site to make sure that works OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Axel,

That module mentioned in your comment did do the job very well. I wasn't matching the user id to an address id correctly which was causing the blank screen when trying to view the details.

That was also what was wrong with my SQL insert attempt so that is working now too. The list of tables in my question are all of the tables that need to be edited if you ever want to alter or insert orders in Magento.

Comment: can you help with query used

Comment: That was a long time ago and I haven't Magento in years. I might not be able to help you much.